# Rails link_to onclick submit does not work in chrome

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have a form that edits several line elements. 
I have a link in my form, that adds a new line to the existing list. I use a link_to to call a controller function. 
Before I call the function I would like to submit the existing data, so any user data does not get lost. 
The link below works fine in Firefox, but does not work in Chrome. 
Can you help me understand why? 
Is there is a better solution to add a line? 
I have not used submit, as I need to pass several parameters to the controller. 
An alternative way could be to save the form when ever it is updated. Is that a better way in Rails?

```
<%= link_to t('.new_budget_line'), create_line_child_economy_child_economy_lines_path(:child_economy_id => @child_economy.id, :category_id => child_economy_category.id, :cost_type => 'direct'), :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consider switching your form submission to a more flexible AJAX style with [UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) - then you'll have greater control over the data being sent, and hopefully have a better chance of diagnosing what browser difference you might be picking up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 <%= link_to t('.new_budget_line'), create_line_child_economy_child_economy_lines_path(:child_economy_id => @child_economy.id, :category_id => child_economy_category.id, :cost_type => 'direct') , :html => {:onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()"}, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
```

Comment: That did unfortunately not work. Then the link did not work in any of the browsers ;-)